# how to do search using angular?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs

I'm using angularjs, i want to search from a table called cycle as shown below, i want to search data using **weeks in cycle**  searching to screenshot 1 . When i search to screen shot 1 the data must display on screen shot 2 and when i select on screenshot 2 must go back to screen shot 1 and display the selected details how can i achieve  this please help.

**model**

```
  public partial class Cycle
{
    public int CycleID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Cycle1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WeeksInCycle { get; set; }
}
```

**screenshot 1**

[image]

**screenshot 2**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build a REST service and use Angular to retrieve the data.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service) is a nice detailed description how to accomplish this.